# Verify if I can use a given directory

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Admin creates an Oracle directory:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY EXAMPLE AS '\\server\share\test';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY EXAMPLE TO JOHN;
```

Admin can test whether the directory exists:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_DIRECTORIES WHERE DIRECTORY_NAME='EXAMPLE'
```

How can John verify whether directory `EXAMPLE` exists? How can he find out what permissions he's been granted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permissions are exposed to a DBA in `DBA_TAB_PRIVS`.

```
SELECT * FROM dba_tab_privs WHERE table_name='EXAMPLE';
```

Your user John will be able to see his grants in `ALL_TAB_PRIVS`.

Comment: Oracle, always so intuitive. Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking form.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: an alternative is the view `ALL_DIRECTORIES` which shows all directories the current user has access to.

Comment: Keep in mind that Oracle directory objects always belong to SYS (even if you grant CREATE ANY DIRECTORY to a user, and create the directory from it... **even though is obviously not recomendated**) and they all share the same namespace. That's why there's no view such USER_DIRECTORIES